# Tensor flow installation success but returning NUMA node zero warning on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu, face-detection

I've just installed tensor flow 2.6.0 via pip install tensor flow on Ubuntu 20.04 with Python 3.8.0 to implement face liveness functionality in face detection project. Requirements are Installed successfully, while I try to run the face detection file on Ubuntu 20.04 server, I am getting the below information and my camera is not getting ready to capture.

> 021-09-17 12:04:19.264912: I tensor flow/stream executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
> 2021-09-17 12:04:19.269784: I tensor flow/stream executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
> 2021-09-17 12:04:19.270044: I tensorflow/stream executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
> 2021-09-17 12:04:19.270500: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
> To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
> 2021-09-17 12:04:19.271031: I tensorflow/stream executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
> 2021-09-17 12:04:19.271255: I tensorflow/stream executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
> 2021-09-17 12:04:19.271469: I tensorflow/stream executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
> 2021-09-17 12:04:19.561394: I tensorflow/stream executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
> 2021-09-17 12:04:19.561630: I tensorflow/stream executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
> 2021-09-17 12:04:19.561829: I tensorflow/stream executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
> 2021-09-17 12:04:19.562014: I tensorflow/core/common runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1504] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3017 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: Quadro P1000, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1

Comment: It is just a warning, it always appears, you can just ignore it.

Comment: Thanks, Dr.snoopy ,but my camera frame is not opening in Ubuntu Why?. Whenever I tried with my local machine(in windows 10) it's working. I installed tensor flow 1.15.0 with python 3.7.3 in windows and in Ubuntu Tensor flow version is 2.6 and python is 3.8.Is there any CUDA dependency with tensor flow 2.6?.  I'm totally confused.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.